# How to do a difficult rebase in O(n) rather than O(n^2)?

Tags: git-rebase

There's this difficult rebase that keeps stumbling on conflicts every other commit. In order to be able to resolve some confusing conflicts, I must sometimes `--abort` and check out the master branch to see what exactly is there (unconfounded by conflict markup, stuff rebased so far, or git's "ours" vs. "theirs" hell). Whenever I do this, I must subsequently re-resolve all conflicts up to that point. This makes the rebase effectively O(n^2).

Is there a better way?

(Note: it **absolutely must** be a rebase, this requirement is a given. Merging is out of the question).

Comment: [There's always the comically oversized hammer of git-rerere.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) Never tried it, don't know if it is helpful in your case. The less silly way would be to have the master branch checked out in a different directory and being able to examine it without aborting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the new (Git 2.30)  new merge strategy: ORT ("Ostensibly Recursive's Twin") will be slightly faster.
But the all process would still be *not* `O(n)`.

Second, do use the [`git worktree` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) in order to checkout `master` in a separate folder (without making a separate clone).
That way, you don't have to abort the merge in progress, and can compare with a copy of your working tree, on `master` branch.

Comment: Thanks! I meant O(n) in the number of "stumbles". If I never redo a "stumble", then it's linear.